# Unexpected commit hash in a tarball on GitHub

Tags: git, hash, github

The following page provides short hash `89b734fd24` of the commit corresponding to the tag `1.1.1`: https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/tree/1.1.1

However, in the following tarball the packed directory is called `jezdez-django_compressor-a66ab32`: https://nodeload.github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/tarball/1.1.1

Typically, the short hash in a tarball matches the commit hash. Where does `a66ab32` come from?

UPDATE: It seems that someone from GitHub has just fixed the hash in tarball for a tag, and now it is consistent. At least, I cannot reproduce the issue anymore.

UPDATE2: The same problem occurs with https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer/tree/0.8.0, tarball contains `stefanfoulis-cmsplugin-filer-f6c10c2` (tag hash) while the commit hash is `3bbbd37`

UPDATE3:

- [22:16]  depends if the tag is a lightweight tag, or not
- [22:16]  lightweight tags are pointers to commits, real tags have their own sha/message/tagger associated with it
- [22:17]  see also: http://progit.org/book/ch2-6.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash is the object id of a tag. It's hard to find the object ids of these tags, but it's possible.

```
$ git show-ref 1.1.1
a66ab32181a6597ec946423f2aecbde9ed113e93 refs/tags/1.1.1

$ git rev-parse 1.1.1
a66ab32181a6597ec946423f2aecbde9ed113e93

$ git show --pretty=raw 1.1.1
tag 1.1.1
Tagger: Jannis Leidel <jannis@leidel.info>

1.1.1 yeah!

commit 89b734fd24c9e172949cac6df29ea591a95f8aa3
tree 042332aaba8b325f9a65697de5c340919cc42f72
parent f226274e4e90c58956753bcd33a406a59e1b419a
parent d683e30dd146bb6db62934a6f561aea27fd84a06
author Jannis Leidel <jannis@leidel.info> 1320241044 +0100
committer Jannis Leidel <jannis@leidel.info> 1320241044 +0100

    Merge branch 'release/1.1.1'
```

The zip has the sha of the commit, the directory has the sha of the actual tag object.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking into that first, I'd say it is probably an annotated tag, possibly signed as well.

These are separate objects and thus have seperate object id in the git object database. The tag refers to a commit id.
(looking into the repo you linked now)

**Edit** Here's what happens:

**`git show a66ab32`**

```
tag 1.1.1
Tagger: Jannis Leidel <jannis@leidel.info>
Date:   Wed Nov 2 14:37:24 2011 +0100

1.1.1 yeah!

commit 89b734fd24c9e172949cac6df29ea591a95f8aa3
Merge: f226274 d683e30
Author: Jannis Leidel <jannis@leidel.info>
Date:   Wed Nov 2 14:37:24 2011 +0100

    Merge branch 'release/1.1.1'
```

So you can see `a66ab32` names the tag, 89b734fd24c9e17 names the corresponding commit

Comment: Could you guide me how I can find `a66ab32` except in the tarball?